# No module named 'openpyxl'",

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-textract

I am trying to write code using the AWS Lambda function to extract Pdf Invoice data from the AWS Textract Service and save the data into Excel. To do this, I installed the openpyxl library, created a zip file for it, and created a layer in lambda function that uses the openpyxl library. I am getting the following error ( No module named 'openpyxl'",). I would appreciate your assistance in resolving it.

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. Please provide detailed description (step by step, with all the commands used) how you created the layer, and how do you test it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Textractor](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-textractor/) `pip install amazon-textract-textractor`? It comes built-in with the export-to-excel features and comes with the lamdba layers pre-built on the official GitHub repository: https://aws-samples.github.io/amazon-textract-textractor/using_in_lambda.html

Note that the available lamdba layer uses [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) instead of openpyxl.

Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of Textractor.